# Do formula fields obey sharing rules?

Tags: formula-field, sharing, cross-object

If I have a formula field that uses cross-object access to obtain a value, if the user has no access (via sharing rules) to the referenced object but otherwise have permission to access the value will the user see a value in the formula field?

For example, let's say I have:

- Object `X__c` which has a field `MyY__c` that is a lookup to object `Y__c`.
- Object `Y__c` with a field `Example__c` (a string).

I then add a formula field on `X__c`, `Formula__c`, that has the expression `MyY__r.Example__c`.

A `Y__c` record is created and the `Example__c` field is set to "Example Text". An `X__c` record is then created and made to reference the `Y__c` record via `MyY__c`.

Now, the user has read permissions for the objects and all fields on both `X__c` and `Y__c`. They also have access to a specific `X__c` record via sharing rules. However they don't have sharing access to the `Y__c` record related to that `X__c`.

What would they see in the `X__c` record's `Formula__c` field? Do we see "Example Text", nothing, or some error about lacking permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User will be able to see the formula field value. Check out this [ref](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_creating_cross_object_simple.htm&type=5).

> If you create a formula that references a field on another object and
> display that formula in your page layout, users can see the field on
> the object even if they don’t have access to that object record. For
> example, if you create a formula field on the Case object that
> references an account field, and display that formula field in the
> case page layout, users can see this field even if they don’t have
> access to the account record.

If the lookup field (`MyY__c`) was also displayed on the `X__c`'s page layout, the user will be able to see this field as well (*as hyperlink*). But, if the user click on the lookup field, then a std error message (*as shown in screenshot below*) will be displayed.

[image]